# Jenkins stage for loop not continuing if for loop fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins stage requirement is for loop should continue even it fails on 1st index value. I tried below code but the for loop doesn't continue if REPO_LIST failed on "A". Any suggestions. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
stages {
    stage('A') {
        when {
            expression {params.ENV == true}
        }
        steps {
            script {
             try {
                              
               def REPO_LIST = [ "A", "B" ]
               
               for ( REPO in REPO_LIST ) {
                    CODE xxxxxxxx
                 }
               }   catch(all) {
                      println "hello"
                      continue;
         }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the try-catch block within your loop surrounding the `CODE xxxx`. Have look at the below.

```
stages {
    stage('A') {
    when {
        expression {params.ENV == true}
    }
      steps {
          script {              
             def REPO_LIST = [ "A", "B" ]
             
             for ( REPO in REPO_LIST ) {
                  try {
                    CODE xxxxxxxx
                    } catch(all) { println "hello"}
                }
          }
       }
   }
}
```